# How do I use NSTableCellPopup without showing a bezel?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

In interface builder when i use an NSTableCellPopup it has a simplified appearance (shown on the right), but when build and populated with data the popup bezel is shown, is there a way to keep the simple bezel-less appearance until the user clicks on the control?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've left the original answer here as it may interest someone later down the line; however, I think I misunderstood what Jared was looking for. To achieve what he's looking for I think it should be as simple as calling [setBordered:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/setBordered%3a)NO on the instance of [NSPopupButtonCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that he is using (the method is inherited from [NSCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCell)).

Original:
I'd recommend looking at the [class reference for NSComboBoxCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBoxCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Specifically, it offers the method [setButtonBordered:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBoxCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSComboBoxCell/setButtonBordered%3a) which allows you to control the appearance of the button border on a NSComboBoxCell used in a table view. That is how I would work to achieve the desired result you show above.